# Spark error: All datanodes are bad. Aborting

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, cluster-computing, amazon-emr

I'm running a Spark job on AWS EMR cluster 1 master, 3 cores each has 16 vCPUs and after about 10 minutes, I'm getting the error below. On Windows machine it runs perfectly fine.

stack trace:

```
20/06/25 15:17:59 ERROR AsyncEventQueue: Listener EventLoggingListener threw an exception
java.io.IOException: All datanodes [DatanodeInfoWithStorage[172.34.18.217:50010,DS-0662bfa1-3e63-4ccc-8493-3deaf3ed2bbf,DISK]] are bad. Aborting...
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.handleBadDatanode(DataStreamer.java:1531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.setupPipelineForAppendOrRecovery(DataStreamer.java:1465)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.processDatanodeError(DataStreamer.java:1237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:657)
```

I tried:
.config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled","true")
.config("spark.shuffle.service.enabled","true");
but that didn't help.

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Is your one node out of disk space?

Comment: nope, there's enough space on the disk

Comment: Can you provide more stack trace for the above error? Also, You can enable logging in EMR and try seeing what is actually going wrong in the log file of driver nodes.

Comment: I added the stack trace

Comment: What is your instance type, EBS volumes per node, and data volumes?

Comment: 5R4XLarge, 16CPU 128GB ram, lots of RAM and HD space, 58GB data. Must be a RAM config issue

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem?